# How to Translate Text of an Image in Real Time With iPhone Camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, camera

I am working on an app that needs to translate the text of an image in realtime with the `iphone` camera.Is there any way to implement it? any sdk or tutorial will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be a combination of the following:

- The open-source Tesseract OCR engine for getting the text from the image(Quite recent iOS wrapper here: https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios)
- One of the translation services discussed in this question for translations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api
- E.g. a tutorial like this on how to get a real-time camera view with overlays: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273

Please note that these are just ideas on how to do this with as fast progress as possible.
Some apps that offer real-time translations even try to find a suitable font and display the translated text at the exact same position as the original text was. I am afraid that this is not possible without investing lots of work and developing your own OCR engine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer i am working on your idea and hope it works

Comment: Maybe you've already found that out as well, but: I've researched a bit further and found out that you can even get the correct positions of the recognized text by using hOCR output. Just set the `tessedit_create_hocr`variable to 1, get the text using `GetHOCRText(0)`, and parse the html you get back. Hope this helps.

Comment: @FD How can I use this method GetHOCRText()?